# Kendo UI Upload control requires additional tab...is there a workaround?

Tags: file-upload, focus, kendo-ui, tab-ordering

The upload control 'Select...' button remains the focus for the duration of 2 tabs when included in a form with additional inputs.

The final output structure is as such and doesn't include any other form elements but the input[type=file] element

```
<div class="k-widget k-upload">
<div class="k-dropzone">
<div class="k-button k-upload-button">
<input name="photos" id="photos" type="file" data-role="upload" autocomplete="off" class="">
<span>Select...</span>
</div>
<em>drop files here to upload</em>
</div>
</div>
```

What is it about this that 
Does not take into consideration the need for a tabbed interface where the button is a primary focus
Does not allow to implement 'focus' on said button

Please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after semi-lengthy discussions and hours of attempts at funny selector work-arounds to resolve this, I came to a conclusion. This is no ordinary conclusion, as it has been passed through the ranks of an Agile system and has been accepted...

There is no spoon. Had to say it...but there's really no solution. The input[type=file] element is poorly designed in ONLY IE. There is *'absolutely'* no way to trick the browser into landing on the pseudo-'button' portion of the element and having the same effect as with all the other elements.

There is no problem at all in browsers like Chrome & Firefox. Don't even need to attempt a script to account for the misbehavior.